# Service Console (classic) macros with Select Email Action/Apply Email Template stopped working

Tags: service-console, macros

### Given

- Service Console (Classic)
- Macros that include instructions `Select Email Action | Apply Email Template`
- All were working

### When

- Some change made

### Then

- Macros stopped working with error `The instruction is not available`
- New macros can't be built that include applying an email template to the Select Email Action macro instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SFDC link [Error 'The instruction is not available' when you use a Macro](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339707&type=1&mode=1&language=en_US) states quite clearly that a change in the page layout can cause this issue and sure enough such a change had been made

> Please remember that the macro will execute as long as the target points to something in the screen. If the Page Layout changed (e.g. publisher removed from the feed layout, Knowledge sidebar removed from the console components....) for a given User this might invalidate the Instructions.

Now, what exactly had happened:

A developer had looked at the Case page layout and noticed a lot of `Email` actions on the Case 'feed-based layout'

To wit, the layout included three Email `Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher`:

[image]

These were in turn

```
API Name
Case.Email     // auto-created by SFDC - standard Email Action on Case Feed Publisher
SendEmail      // global quick action
Case.SendEmail // object-specific quick action
```

The developer removed `Case.Email` from the Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher thinking it was superfluous to the `SendEmail` quick actions.

> Wham, macros stopped working

Restoring the page layout fixed the issue

> Update: Recently, macros stopped again (with a gack). Two separate resolutions were required:

1. Removing conflicting actions from the Case feed-based layout resolved this: Specifically, leave `Case.Email` and remove any global or object-based `SendEmail` action from the `Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher` portion of the layout.
2. Ensuring the running user also had as a default page layout the feed-based layout rather than the non-feed-based layout.